# Translating site for different languages?

Tags: php

I have read a lot of different "complicated" approaches to translate a PHP site, so I want to ask if the simple approach is some how bad?

With simple I mean like this one Lang file.

```
 $lang1="Hello";  ///////in English
 $lang1="Hallo";  ///////in Other language, ex. German
```

Using simple if statement ex. like cookie[en] or if cookie[de] (I can do whatever if statement based IP, based cookie etc) to determine what language to use

EDIT:
Example PHP file:

```
include_once("lang.php");
    bla bla code
    echo"$lang1"; bla bla more php do code
```

Comment: You can get the users `ip`, then you can check in what country they are looking from. You can then change it, with some checks.

Comment: you will want to extract all the strings, and then based on either IP or the user preferences load an XML or JSON object containing all of the strings for the application.  Since this is in PHP and is rendered client side, you could just have those files stored on the server and referenced as such.

Comment: I know this is not an issue here, I just want to ask if the language file containing simple PHP variables is OK way to go, because there are so many different approaches on the web, and no-one mentions the simplest way .